# Python code slowing down when wrapped in a function

Tags: python-3.x, dataset, pytorch

I'm reading and processing a file (using the same bit of code) which runs at two very different speeds: 1. scripted (50K+ iterations per second) and 2. wrapped in function (~300 iterations per second). I really can't figure out why there are such massive differences in reading time consumption.

The module structure (unused and irrelevant files omitted. The code is at the end.):

```
| experiments/
|--| experiment_runner.py
|
| module/
|--| shared/
|--|--| dataloaders.py
|--|--| data.py
```

In `data.py` we have the method (`load`, the class wrapping the method inherits from `torch.utils.data.Dataset`) actually loading the file. In `dataloaders.py` I prepare the arguments to pass to `load`, wrapped in a function for each dataset that I'm using. This is then passed to a `loader` function, which handles splitting the dataset and so on.

In `experiment_runner` then is where the differences in speed happen. If I use the dataset functions in `dataloaders.py` the loading happens at around 300 iterations/second. If I copy the code from the function and throw it directly into the `experiment_runner`, still using the `loader` function from `dataloaders.py` (so, not wrapped in a function for each dataset), the loading happens at roughly 50000 iterations / second. I am at a complete loss as to why wrapping code in a function would alter the speed of it that drastically.

Now the actual code:

data.py:

```py
    def load(self, dataset: str = 'train', skip_header = True, **kwargs) -> None:
        fp = open(self.data_files[dataset])

        if skip_header:
            next(fp)

        data = []
        for line in tqdm(self.reader(fp), desc = f'loading {self.name} ({dataset})'):
            data_line, datapoint = {}, base.Datapoint()

            for field in self.train_fields:
                idx = field.index if self.ftype in ['CSV', 'TSV'] else field.cname
                data_line[field.name] = self.process_doc(line[idx].rstrip())
                data_line['original'] = line[idx].rstrip()

            for field in self.label_fields:
                idx = field.index if self.ftype in ['CSV', 'TSV'] else field.cname
                if self.label_preprocessor:
                    data_line[field.name] = self.label_preprocessor(line[idx].rstrip())
                else:
                    data_line[field.name] = line[idx].rstrip()

            for key, val in data_line.items():
                setattr(datapoint, key, val)
            data.append(datapoint)
        fp.close()

        if self.length is None:
            # Get the max length
            lens = []
            for doc in data:
                for f in self.train_fields:
                    lens.append(len([tok for tok in getattr(doc, getattr(f, 'name'))]))
            self.length = max(lens)

        if dataset == 'train':
            self.data = data
        elif dataset == 'dev':
            self.dev = data
        elif dataset == 'test':
            self.test = data
```

dataloaders.py:

```py
def loader(args: dict, **kwargs):
    """Loads the dataset.
    :args (dict): Dict containing arguments to load dataaset.
    :returns: Loaded and splitted dataset.
    """
    dataset = GeneralDataset(**args)
    dataset.load('train', **kwargs)

    if (args['dev'], args['test']) == (None, None):  # Only train set is given.
        dataset.split(dataset.data, [0.8, 0.1, 0.1], **kwargs)

    elif args['dev'] is not None and args['test'] is None:  # Dev set is given, test it not.
        dataset.load('dev', **kwargs)
        dataset.split(dataset.data, [0.8], **kwargs)

    elif args['dev'] is None and args['test'] is not None:  # Test is given, dev is not.
        dataset.split(dataset.data, [0.8], **kwargs)
        dataset.dev_set = dataset.test
        dataset.load('test', **kwargs)

    else:  # Both dev and test sets are given.
        dataset.load('dev', **kwargs)
        dataset.load('test', **kwargs)

    return dataset


def binarize(label: str) -> str:
    if label in ['0', '1']:
        return 'pos'
    else:
        return 'neg'


def datal(path: str, cleaners: base.Callable, preprocessor: base.Callable = None):
    args = {'data_dir': path,
            'ftype': 'csv',
            'fields': None,
            'train': 'dataset.csv', 'dev': None, 'test': None,
            'train_labels': None, 'dev_labels': None, 'test_labels': None,
            'sep': ',',
            'tokenizer': lambda x: x.split(),
            'preprocessor': preprocessor,
            'transformations': None,
            'length': None,
            'label_preprocessor': binarize,
            'name': 'First dataset.'
            }

    ignore = base.Field('ignore', train = False, label = False, ignore = True)
    d_text = base.Field('text', train = True, label = False, ignore = False, ix = 6, cname = 'text')
    d_label = base.Field('label', train = False, label = True, cname = 'label', ignore = False, ix = 5)

    args['fields'] = [ignore, ignore, ignore, ignore, ignore, d_label, d_text]

    return loader(args)
```

And for the purposes:
experiment_runner.py

```
from module.dataloaders import datal, loader

dataset = datal() # Slow: 300-ish iterations/second

# Fast version: 50000 iter/second
def binarize(label: str) -> str:
    if label in ['0', '1']:
        return 'pos'
    else:
        return 'neg'

args = {'data_dir': path,
        'ftype': 'csv',
        'fields': None,
        'train': 'dataset.csv', 'dev': None, 'test': None,
        'train_labels': None, 'dev_labels': None, 'test_labels': None,
        'sep': ',',
        'tokenizer': lambda x: x.split(),
        'preprocessor': preprocessor,
        'transformations': None,
        'length': None,
        'label_preprocessor': binarize,
        'name': 'First dataset.'
        }

ignore = base.Field('ignore', train = False, label = False, ignore = True)
d_text = base.Field('text', train = True, label = False, ignore = False, ix = 6, cname = 'text')
d_label = base.Field('label', train = False, label = True, cname = 'label', ignore = False, ix = 5)

args['fields'] = [ignore, ignore, ignore, ignore, ignore, d_label, d_text]

dataset = loader(args)
```

I would ideally prefer to keep the dataset functions (e.g. `datal`) wrapped to keep the logic separate but with this speed decrease, that's not feasible.

Comment: can you delete all `__pycache__`  folders and recheck?

Comment: @cozek okay that changed something. Now both loops are running at the same speed (slow version). But why would that be linked to the `__pycache__` folders?